# Why does pos() report matches even with non-capturing groups?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I want to match the placeholders (bare `?`, without quotes) in a parameterized SQL query like this:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col1`=? WHERE `col2`=? AND `x`="??as"
```

(I know I should be using `SQL::Parser` instead. Bear with me here.)

This regex `` (?:`.+?`)|(?:'.+?')|(?:".+?")|(\?) `` matches the bare question marks in `` `col1`=? `` and `` `col2`=? `` but skips the question marks inside the double quotes in `` `x`="??as" ``, as I want it to. You can see this working at https://regex101.com/r/iH4aV2/3.

Now that regex is run by PCRE. If I run this bit of Perl:

```pl
# same regex and test string
my $x = 'UPDATE `table` SET `col1`=? WHERE `col2`=? AND `x`="??as"';          

while ($x =~ /(?:`.+?`)|(?:'.+?')|(?:".+?")|(\?)/g) {
    print "A:".pos($x)."\n";
}
```

I get:

```
A:14
A:25
A:27
A:40
A:42
A:50
A:57
```

I was expecting to get only the positions of the bare question marks, like on the regex101 site:

```
A:27
A:42
```

Why is this happening? Can I make Perl's regex engine behave like PCRE?

Comment: I'd suggest changing the pattern to `while($x =~ /(?:(?:\`.+?\`)|(?:'.+')|(?:".+?"))(*SKIP)(*F)|\?/g) { print "A:".pos($x)."\n"; }`. But I guess there might be other ways out. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/C8iM3A)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your code but nothing is printed.

Comment: Basically, I suggest to only match `?` and skip all the `\`...\``, `'...'`, and `"..."` substrings. Are you sure you do not have any escaped sequences in your input? You cannot use lazy dot matching then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah that's what (?: is for, it consumes the quoted strings but they won't be included in the matches. Let's also assume for a moment I don't have any escaped sequences, so I can at least have some success.

Comment: No, non-capturing groups match (and consume) the text, they do not put the submatches into the capture group stack. To skip them, I used `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you know why pcre and perl behave differently here? this is annoying.

Comment: I believe there is no discrepancy between PCRE and Perl in this regard.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you open https://regex101.com/r/iH4aV2/3 you'll see pcre returns only 2 offsets while perl returns 7. That looks like a discrepancy to me.

Comment: That is regex101 idiosyncrasy to only display *captured values* rather than all groups in the *MATCH INFORMATION* pane (a match value is usually a zeroth group). You should pay attention to the *matches* you see highlighted in the input text pane.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. that makes sense. ok, I'll see if I can use (*SKIP) and (*FAIL) as you suggested

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot why did you remove the comment from @WiktorStribizew? I figured I'd put it up there in case people tripped like I have. Honest question, I don't understand (I may have had too much coffee today).

Comment: It answers your question (or at least, points out that the premise of the question was flawed), so it belongs in an answer, not the question. If @WiktorStribiżew doesn't feel like writing an answer, feel free to copy the comment into an answer with attribution and make it community wiki.

Comment: As I said, there should be a cleaner way, and Daniel posted it. I had no time digging into this all, and the details about regex101.com UI do not constitute an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "details about regex101.com UI do not constitute an answer" They do when the question is "why is Perl regex doing X but regex101.com doing Y?" But you're right, a really complete answer would not only explain that both Perl and regex101.com are actually doing the same thing, but also show how to skip matches for non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to check if the capturing parens actually captured something before checking `pos`:

```
my $x = 'UPDATE `table` SET `col1`=? WHERE `col2`=? AND "x"="??as"';
while($x =~ /(?:`.+?`)|(?:'.+')|(?:".+?")|(\?)/g) {
  if (defined($1)) {
    print "A:".pos($x)."\n";
  }
}
```

This yields the desired results.

(I mean, you can use the fancy `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` verbs mentioned in comments, but this seems cleaner)